# Understanding the 'axis' parameter in the softmax activation function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, activation

Suppose i have an input tensor carrying one embedded word per timestep, eg for a time window of 5 and word embedding vector width of 64 i get the shape:

`(None, 5, 64, 1)`

I apply 4 filters with a kernel shape of (1, 64) to look for specific words at each time step, each filter produces 1 value per timestep denoting "word/meaning exists" or "word/meaning does not exist". It produces an output tensor of shape:

`(None, 5, 1, 4)`

How do i define the 'axis' parameter of the softmax layer such that the outputs of all convolutions **per timestep** are normalized, like in a classification task?

More specifically, i want the output to look like the following (height is time, width is channels):

```
[[[.1, .4, .4, .1]]
 [[.9,  0,  0, .1]]
 [[.8,  0, .1, .1]]
 [[ 0,  1,  0,  0]]
 [[.6,. 1, .1, .2]]]
```

Ie the components per row/timestep add up to one, the softmax should only normalize rows.

Code snippet:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(
    filters=words_of_interest,
    kernel_size=(1, embedding_length),
    strides=(1, embedding_length),
    padding="same")
)
model.add(layers.Softmax(axis=3)) # <- is this correct for what i described above?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all values of axis its okay. Tensorflow normalized the values of the array in same way. Here you can check the difference between **tensor** and **normalized** using below code.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

array = np.random.random((5, 4))
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(array)

norm0 = tf.keras.activations.softmax(tensor, axis=0)
norm1 = tf.keras.activations.softmax(tensor, axis=1)
norm2 = tf.keras.activations.softmax(tensor, axis=2)
norm3 = tf.keras.activations.softmax(tensor, axis=3)

print(sum(tensor[0]))
print(sum[norm0[0]])
print(sum[norm1[0]])
print(sum[norm2[0]])
print(sum[norm3[0]])
```